# Logcat keep showing download when I turn on the wifi

Tags: java, android, logcat

When I connect my phone to the computer, the logcat was spammed by the download messages.
It only stop after i disconnect from the wifi.
Here's part of the logcat.

```
    05-15 20:58:29.465: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:29.706: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11502 starting
05-15 20:58:29.856: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:29.936: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11502 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:30.216: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:30.256: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:30.466: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11503 starting
05-15 20:58:30.526: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:30.617: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11503 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:30.627: D/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11503 already finished; skipping
05-15 20:58:30.867: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:30.897: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:31.027: I/art(1080): Heap trim of managed (duration=3.784526ms, advised=184KB) and native (duration=2.197467ms, advised=444KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 57%.
05-15 20:58:31.127: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11504 starting
05-15 20:58:31.478: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:31.578: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11504 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:31.848: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:31.858: I/art(912): Heap trim of managed (duration=2.472150ms, advised=92KB) and native (duration=1.678621ms, advised=4KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 57%.
05-15 20:58:31.888: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:32.198: I/art(554): Heap trim of managed (duration=20.021366ms, advised=2MB) and native (duration=2.563711ms, advised=1320KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 65%.
05-15 20:58:32.198: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11505 starting
05-15 20:58:32.248: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:32.328: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11505 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:32.579: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:32.619: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:32.849: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11506 starting
05-15 20:58:32.909: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:32.979: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11506 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:33.249: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:33.289: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:33.349: I/art(1080): Heap trim of managed (duration=4.059210ms, advised=192KB) and native (duration=2.136426ms, advised=444KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 63%.
05-15 20:58:33.540: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11507 starting
05-15 20:58:33.580: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:33.670: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11507 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:33.700: D/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11507 already finished; skipping
05-15 20:58:33.890: I/art(912): Heap trim of managed (duration=2.258508ms, advised=128KB) and native (duration=1.678620ms, advised=0B) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 55%.
05-15 20:58:33.980: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:34.010: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:34.240: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11508 starting
05-15 20:58:34.301: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:34.411: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11508 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:34.451: D/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11508 already finished; skipping
05-15 20:58:34.661: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:34.711: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:34.971: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11509 starting
05-15 20:58:35.011: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:35.081: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11509 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:35.332: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:35.352: I/art(1080): Heap trim of managed (duration=3.570883ms, advised=28KB) and native (duration=1.861743ms, advised=432KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 67%.
05-15 20:58:35.382: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:35.652: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11510 starting
05-15 20:58:35.822: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:35.942: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11510 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:36.002: I/art(912): Heap trim of managed (duration=2.044865ms, advised=108KB) and native (duration=1.220815ms, advised=0B) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 59%.
05-15 20:58:36.223: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:36.343: I/art(554): Heap trim of managed (duration=20.051884ms, advised=2MB) and native (duration=2.594232ms, advised=1320KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 65%.
05-15 20:58:36.353: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:36.613: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11511 starting
05-15 20:58:36.833: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:36.963: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11511 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:37.214: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:37.254: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:37.474: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11512 starting
05-15 20:58:37.524: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:37.574: I/art(1080): Heap trim of managed (duration=2.838395ms, advised=92KB) and native (duration=2.105906ms, advised=444KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 36%.
05-15 20:58:37.594: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11512 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:37.854: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:37.894: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:38.155: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11513 starting
05-15 20:58:38.205: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:38.495: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11513 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:38.875: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:38.915: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:39.136: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11514 starting
05-15 20:58:39.196: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:39.286: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11514 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:39.316: D/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11514 already finished; skipping
05-15 20:58:39.346: I/art(912): Heap trim of managed (duration=1.922784ms, advised=96KB) and native (duration=1.159774ms, advised=0B) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 56%.
05-15 20:58:39.566: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:39.596: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:39.786: I/art(1080): Heap trim of managed (duration=3.570884ms, advised=132KB) and native (duration=2.227987ms, advised=448KB) heaps. Managed heap utilization of 58%.
05-15 20:58:39.826: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11515 starting
05-15 20:58:39.987: I/DownloadManager(1080): Ignoring Content-Length since Transfer-Encoding is also defined
05-15 20:58:40.077: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11515 finished with status SUCCESS
05-15 20:58:40.117: D/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11515 already finished; skipping
05-15 20:58:40.327: W/AmanattoDataUpdater(912): Amanatto data needs to be removed but session is null. The data will be removed by removing all personalized dictionary files.
05-15 20:58:40.377: I/LatinIME:LogUtils(912): Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 44 ; date = 1393228245
05-15 20:58:40.597: I/DownloadManager(1080): Download 11516 starting
```

I suspect some process's running in the background but I'm not able to detect it.
Anyone has a clue?
Thanks.

**Edit:
Okay. I've pinned down the app that caused this problem.
It's the google keyboard.
For some reason it keeps downloading the dictionary but failed.**

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Google Keyboard app data solved the problem for me.